# R wrong binning in histogram

Tags: r, histogram

This is my data

```
x <- c(10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4)
```

for which I generate a histogram:

```
hist(x, col="green")
```

and this is the histogram:

[image: Histogram]

My question is why the first bar is binned differently than the others? I think there should be additional bin (9.9, 10.0> because default righ-closed intervals are used.

Answer (score 0):

1.you can use the right parameter and set it to FALSE

```
x <- c(10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4)
hist(x, col="green", right = FALSE)
```

2. Specify a vector of break points to control the bin edges precisely

`hist(x, col="green", breaks = seq(9.9, 10.5, 0.1))  # Breaks at 9.9, 10.0, 10.1,` ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but:

1) does not help - doubled bar apperas only on the oposite side of histogram.
2) my question was not how to create bins in a histogram, but whether the default binning (Sturges) has a bug because it incorrectly closes the intervals in the extreme class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function to setup the `breaks`, e.g.,

```
hist(x, breaks = \(v) {
    u <- sort(unique(v))
    d <- min(diff(u)) / 2
    seq(min(u) - d, max(u) + d, length.out = length(u) + 1)
})
```

[image]

Or, you can use `barplot` instead

```
barplot(values ~ ., stack(table(x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was not how to create bins in a histogram, but whether the default binning (Sturges) has a bug because it incorrectly closes the intervals in the extreme class.